# trouble using hidden input value with quotes

Tags: php, input, quotes, hidden

I searched the site and didn't find a solution. My problem is that I've got a hidden input that I want to send via the post method that has quotes in it. I've tried using addslashes() and I get the same problem. It looks something like this right now:

```
<?php $value = 'I\'ve got \"some\" random text with quotes'; ?>
<input name="example" value="<?=$value?>">
```

And I get most of the the text showing in my form because the quotes aren't being ignored AARGH! ;) So how to I get text with quote into a hidden input?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would convert them so they validate and avoid confusion:

```
<?php $value = 'I&#039;ve got &quot;some&quot; random text with quotes'; ?>
<input name="example" value="<?=$value?>">
```

Try to avoid using double quotes with PHP strings, as PHP will search the entire string for a variable to parse, regardless if the string contains one. They are slower than single quotes. Not so much anymore these days, but still a good practice to use single quotes for strings.

Comment: That's a great idea. Do you have an idea as to how to convert it automatically? The way I have it set up I could do some sort of conversion before or after it's inserted into the database and still work in the hidden input.

Comment: Yep check out the function htmlentities(); and read about the argument ENT_QUOTES

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php $value = "I've got \"some\" random text with quotes"; ?>
```

when you output this will result in the following?

```
<input name="example" value="I've got \"some\" random text with quotes">
```

Comment: Yes, something like that. I put a different value in my question just to illustrate what I meant.